# Java Spring bean with private constructor

Tags: java, spring, constructor, javabeans, private

Is it possible in Spring that a class for bean doesn't have a public constructor but only a private one?
Will this private constructor be invoked when the bean is created?

Comment: How about giving it a try and then posting the results?

Comment: It is difficult - I don't have all source.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Yes, Spring can invoke private constructors. If it finds a constructor with the right arguments, regardless of visibility, it will use reflection to set its constructor to be accessible.

Comment: Could you please give me the reference to docs? Constructor has parameters, and in xml file to this arguments assigned values.

Comment: you mean if a bean has specifically something like private bean() { ... } spring can invoke that? How is that possible, that defies the whole purpose of "private".

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably wrong about it only being no-arg constructors. I'm just going by what I've noticed on my own projects. I can't say I've ever seen it in the Spring documentation anywhere. But this is the javadoc for the class that is responsible for doing the instantiation. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#instantiateClass(java.lang.reflect.Constructor,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: @Ashkan It is possible using reflection. In particular, the Spring BeanUtils class uses a class called ReflectionUtils to make the constructor accessible. See javadocs for Constructor.setAccessible().

Comment: @Kevin Stembridge you are correct, it is possible using Reflection.

Comment: I think yes, it possible use private constructor by means of reflection. May be spring do it.

Comment: +1: Note that if you've got a non-Spring-aware third-party bean implementation, you'll have to use XML to configure it (including setting what values to pass as arguments to the constructor, if necessary). Not that that should be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use a factory method to create beans rather than relying on a default constructor, from [The IoC container: Instantiation using an instance factory method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method):

```
<!-- the factory bean, which contains a method called createInstance() -->
<bean id="serviceLocator" class="com.foo.DefaultServiceLocator">
  <!-- inject any dependencies required by this locator bean -->
</bean>

<!-- the bean to be created via the factory bean -->
<bean id="exampleBean"
      factory-bean="serviceLocator"
      factory-method="createInstance"/>
```

This has the advantage that you can use non-default constructors for your bean, and the dependencies for the factory method bean can be injected as well.

Comment: interesting, but I cannot find factory. May be exists another way?

Comment: @Matthew: He appears to be retrofitting Spring around some fugly third-party code. That's just _bound_ to be messy.

Comment: @Donal, no I didn't understand what he said in the comment.

Comment: Could you please tell what would be the java config equivalent for this xml config please?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Private constructors are invoked by spring.
Consider my code:

Bean definition file:

```
<bean id="message" class="com.aa.testp.Message">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="Hi Nice"/>
    </bean>
```

Bean class:

```
package com.aa.testp;

public class Message {

    private String message;

    private Message(String msg) {
       // You may add your log or print statements to check execution or invocation
        message = msg;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(" Hi " + message);
    }

}
```

The above code works fine. Hence, spring invoked the private constructor.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this using Spring Java configuration (not xml based)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes ! Spring can access private constructor.
It will works internally like below code.

```
 try {
    Class clazz = Class.forName("A"); // A - Fully qualified class name
    Constructor constructor[] = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors();
    constructor[0].setAccessible(true);
    A a = (A) constructor[0].newInstance();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would normally have a static factory method in such beans, you can specify that method for spring to get an instance of that bean. See [3.3.1.3 here.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html)  This is the way it's recommended by Spring, rather than going against visibility restrictions.

Comment: strange, there are no static method, no public constructor but when I do debug - private constructor invoked! by sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl

Comment: Without specifics/code it won't be possible to comment any further!

Comment: I suppose you are wrong. There are no specific code - I see in debugger only standard sun/spring methods.

Comment: @Ashkan: I suspect you're getting the -1 votes because you're wrong. Spring _can_ peek behind the curtain (unless there's a strict security manager in place and the Spring code isn't marked as trusted).

Comment: @Donal Fellows thanks! Probably! But the rest of my comment is correct and is what is in Spring docs actually so I'm not sure what's -1s are for. I can remove the 1st sentence if it's wrong though. So, if you have a constructor that is explicitly marked private it can still be used by Spring, is that what we are saying?

Comment: @Ashkan: It's _very bad style_ to go against visibility restrictions. Don't do it! Or if you do, feel very bad about it. (Spring does it because it wants to split the definition of a bean from its configuration, but they're typically still closely linked. This question happens to be about the exceptional case where that's not true…)

Comment: @Donal Fellows: Exactly, hence my initial reply. I just can't understand why he would want to do that, what is he trying to achieve, despite me and Matthew asking repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Spring will never call private constructor as Bean scope. If do it will through the below error.

Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class. Nested exception is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class.