# Configure TypeRepresentationStrategy for Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-layout, spring-data-neo4j

We are currently working on a Java project with neo4j.

We use [Spring Data Neo4j](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j) and get most of the information out of the [Good Relationships](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/pdf/spring-data-neo4j-reference.pdf) book.

This document states, that the standard entity type representation in the graph is [IndexingNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.0.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/typerepresentation/IndexingNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.html).

For our project we would prefer the one with *subreference nodes*.

How can we configure neo4j to use this strategy when working with repositories. We started with the HelloWorld example, so we currently have a repository interface as follows:

```
public interface IWebsiteGraphRepository extends GraphRepository<Website> {}
```

Additionally we have our node entity (I omit most of the irrelevant code):

```
@NodeEntity
public class Website {
    ...
}
```

Can anyone provide a small example of how to set the [TypeRepresentationStrategy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/core/TypeRepresentationStrategy.html#postEntityCreation%28S,%20java.lang.Class%29) ?

Can this be done in the Spring configuration?

The config would be:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="neo4jTransactionManager" />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.base">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" 
                  expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/neo4j-db" />
<neo4j:repositories base-package="my.base.packages.repositories" />
```

**Edit:**

After another session I finally was able to get it to work! I started based on Michael Hungers answer, but was not able to create the Bean. I found where his example may be from: [gitHub](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/blob/3d9c549f8ad20bb0a11a72c68f42bb199d677a6a/spring-data-neo4j-aspects/src/test/resources/org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/support/SubReferenceTypeRepresentationStrategyOverride-context.xml). This, however, still did not work for me. I began looking deeper into the source code of the TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory class. I found out, that Strategy is a private enumeration. This is the second constructor arg I tried to provide. In my project it did never detect it as of type Strategy.

First I was a little sceptic, because Strategy is private. I mean, I couldn't even instanciate a TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory in Code, because it would not find the type Strategy. I soon found out, that Spring supposedly can do things like that: [Beans with private constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254496/java-spring-bean-with-private-constructor).

In the end I had to adjust Michaels solution, as it was not identifying the constructor argument whatsoever. No matter what I did. Maybe it's my setup, I really don't know. But finally I came up with the solution to create a [bean from the private enumeration](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.ch/2007/05/creating-spring-bean-from-java-5-enum.html) and provide this as a reference to the constructor:

```
<bean id="subref" factory-method="valueOf"
class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.Strategy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>SubRef</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="typeRepresentationStrategyFactory"
    class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="delegatingGraphDatabase" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="subref" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
<bean id="typeRepresentationStrategyFactory" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="graphDatabaseService"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="SubRef"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

The bean fails to create with the error 'Could not resolve matching constructor'. I tried without the constructor arg Subref, and it works. I even tried adding the type or name property to the constructor-arg tag. It didn't change anything.

I found the constructor:
`public TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory(GraphDatabase graphDatabaseService,Strategy strategy)`
and I don't really see why this doesn't work. Is it because the Strategy type is private for the TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory?

Comment: @Rob Unfortunately I had little time for testing around. I will have some spare time the next few days and try it again. I would really like to mark it as 'answer' ;) but I can't do it yet.

Comment: Well if you can throw the code that you have up on to GitHub I would be happy to provide an assist.

Comment: Interesting, b/c I took the code sample out of the config of a working Test. Can you share your config? (Perhaps on the Neo4j Google group or Spring Forums)

Comment: I created this post on the spring forums: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?127437-Spring-Data-Neo4j-Using-SubReference-TypeRepresentationStrategy

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
<bean id="typeRepresentationStrategyFactory" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="graphDatabaseService"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <value type="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.Strategy">SubRef</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```