# How to make a factory that creates singleton in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have an object that must be created using a factory method:

```
public class FrameFactory {
    public static Frame createFrame() throws IOException, SerializationException {
        BXMLSerializer bxmlSerializer = new BXMLSerializer();
        return (Frame)bxmlSerializer.readObject(FrameFactory.class, "/gui/MainFrame.bxml");
    }
}
```

The Spring call to get the mean will be something like this:

```
<bean id="frame" class="Frame" factory-method="createFrame"/>
```

However, I want this object to be singleton.

My question is that does Spring has some ready-made method to make a singleton OR I have to implement the singleton pattern myself in the FrameFactory?

Thank you very much.

Comment: are you getting different object? I don't think so. Print the `hashCode` of the returned `Frame`object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use a static factory method, the correct syntax is :

```
<bean id="frame" class="FrameFactory " factory-method="createFrame"/>
```

and you do not have to create a factory bean. By default, `frame` bean will be instanciated as a singleton bean.

Comment: OP want to get `Frame` object from `BXMLSerializer` object, is it possible without using factory method?

Comment: [Be careful not to confuse the Spring singleton with the Singleton Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637864/singleton-design-pattern-vs-singleton-beans-in-spring-container). You can create two beans the way you are doing it (with different ids) and they will not be ==

Comment: I know it. But if a programmer creates 2 beans of same class without reason and is surprised not having a true singleton, **he** is to blame, not Spring.