# What is the meaning of "Singleton is per process and per class loader"?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, singleton

"Just Spring" book says:

"Note that there is a subtle difference between the instance obtained using the Java Singleton pattern and Spring Singleton. Spring Singleton is a singleton per context or container, whereas the Java Singleton is per process and per class loader."

I do understand what "Spring Singleton is a singleton per context or container" means, but i don't understand what "Java Singleton is per process and per class loader" means. Could you please explain the last qoute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Plain Java

The singleton pattern is a per classloader pattern. This is due to the nature of how that pattern is implemented.

```java
public class MySingleton {

  private static final MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();

  private MySingleton() {}

  public static MySingleton() getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Each classloader has a copy of the class and thus each classloader will create an instance of `MySingleton`. And thus the singleton pattern is per classloader.

The problem is that because this is per classloader you might even run into a `ClassCastException` when classloader X and classloader Y have both the same class. This is because class identity is based on the classname + the classloader it is loaded in. (This is often an issue with JDBC Drivers in an application server, when the application also includes those drivers).

### Spring

Now Spring will create an instance per `AppplicationContext` (aka the context or container).

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public MySingleton mySingleton() {
    return new MySingleton();
  }
}
```

Now when doing `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfiguration.class)`. Spring will create an instance of `MySingleton` and will so do so each time one does `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfiguration.class)`. So if you create another one, you will get a new instance. The instance is dedicated to that container. Hence a singleton per container.

See also [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637864/singleton-design-pattern-vs-singleton-beans-in-spring-container) question/answer.